# Python 3.6 - file.write() not actually writing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

In case you didn't catch it in the title, this is Python 3.6

I'm running into an issue where I *was* able to write to a file, and now I cannot. ***The crazy thing is that this was working fine earlier.***

I'm trying to either append my file if it exists, or write to a new file if it doesn't exist.

**main_area_text** represents the div tag text below

```
<div id="1131607" align="center" 
style="width:970px;padding:0px;margin:0px;overflow:visible;text-
align:center"></div>
```

and below is my code:

```
main_area_text = #this is equal to the html text above
                 #I've verified this with a watch during debugging
                 #But this doesn't actually matter, because you can put
                 #anything in here and it still doesn't work
html_file_path = os.getcwd() + "\\data\\myfile.html"
if os.path.isfile(html_file_path):
    print("File exists!")
    actual_file = open(html_file_path, "a")
    actual_file.write(main_area_text)
else:
    print("File does not exist!")
    actual_file = open(html_file_path, "w")
    actual_file.write(main_area_text)
```

Earlier, in it's working state, I could create/write/append to .html and .txt files.

> NOTE: If the file **doesn't exist**, the program still creates a new file... It's just empty.

I'm somewhat new to the python language, so I realize it's very possible that I could be overlooking something simple. (It's actually why I'm writing this code, to just familiarize myself with python.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the file open somewhere else?

Comment: I suspect the issue is you aren't closing your file. This is why you should always use a `with` statement to open files. Then they are closed automatically.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain +1 for a good question. This was actually the first thing I double, triple, checked before coming to SO. At one point, there was a stale instance of python running that was keeping this file open, but that was not the actual source of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not closing your file, the data isn't being flushed to disk. Instead try this:

```py
main_area_text = "stuff"
html_file_path = os.getcwd() + "\\data\\myfile.html"
if os.path.isfile(html_file_path):
    print("File exists!")
    with open(html_file_path, "a") as f:
        f.write(main_area_text)
else:
    print("File does not exist!")
    with open(html_file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(main_area_text)
```

The python [with statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) will handle flushing the data to disk and closing the data automatically. It's generally good practice to use `with` when handling files.